# Java bug: incorrect time in MSK

Tags: java, windows, windows-8, timezone, dst

I found that Java gives incorrect time in MSK timezone, ignoring operating system data:

[image]

As you see, the Java time is hour ahead.

The code is follows:

```
package tests;

import java.util.Date;

public class Try_CurrentTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(new Date());

    }
}
```

java version is 1.8.0_25

We have no DST.

Is it possible to fix?

**UPDATE**

It doesn't think we have DST, because `TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime( new Date() )` returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [Timezone Data Versions in the JRE Software](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html) chart.  The change you are referring to was made in tzdata 2014f - which was first introduced in TZUpdater 1.4.6, or JRE 1.8 update 31.  You said you are running 1.8 update 25.

Simply update your Java runtime to the current version.